# Image mapping using a deep learning network while images have additional input parameter

Tags: deep-learning, image

I'm using a UNet to perform image mapping using medical images. Basically, I have a training set that contains original images and target images. However, the images have another parameter: angle. This parameter is related to the artifact in my training set. Basically, when the angle of this image is large, the artifact is strong. This angle parameter is already known.

My problem is I do not know how to add this parameter in the network. If I only use images with strong artifact to train and apply the net to strong artifact image, the result is good. But, I want to train all these images together since I have to cope with all these images with different angles.

How do I solve this problem?